# Why some PluralsightIQ assessments does not show relevant tag

Tags: support, bug, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I have finish a few PluralsightIQ assessments and wanted to share that in my SO developer story. For `express` the tag was automatically added, and for `angular` there is no tag added. What is the reason for this?[image]